# ICollectionView Filter issue wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection, icollectionview

I am trying to filter the ICollection but the filter is not getting applied and instead it gives me all records. is there any issue in the predicate ? so there are two methods where the filter is applied on collection. First it filters records for SW_Version and then in the second filter it filters for matching id. basically i am implementing search functionality.

```
   public void Updateswlist()
    {
        CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<SPFetchCREntity>(crentities.ToList());
        AllCRSP = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CRmappings2);
        SearchMU = SelectedSW.SW_Version;
        AllCRSP.Filter = obj =>
        {
            SPFetchCREntity entity = obj as SPFetchCREntity;
            return obj != null && entity.SW_Version == SearchMU.ToString();
        };
        AllCRSP.Refresh();
```

2nd Filter

```
        public void searchMUID()
    {
        AllCRSP.Filter = obj =>
        {
            SPFetchCREntity entity = obj as SPFetchCREntity;
            return obj != null && entity.MU_Identifier == Mupass.ToString();
        };
        AllCRSP.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to filter by both SW_Version and MU_Identifier simultaneously?

Comment: Is the source of the CVS set to CRmappings2?

Comment: @mm8 No they happen on different screens. but the second filtered is applied on the view of first filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second filter overwrites the first one. If you want to be able to filter by both properties, you need to include both conditions in your predicate:

```
public void searchMUID()
{
    string Mupass = "";
    AllCRSP.Filter = obj =>
    {
        SPFetchCREntity entity = obj as SPFetchCREntity;
        return obj != null && entity.SW_Version == SearchMU.ToString() && entity.MU_Identifier == Mupass.ToString();
    };
    AllCRSP.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: This works but i found the problem . Since i am adding a filter in this ` public void Updateswlist()` and i am again doing a filter on the view from `public void searchMUID()` the view from the derived first filter is gone and so i am unable to search the record. suppose if i clear the filter of AllCRSP from second method will it clear all filters of first method also ?

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer using ReactiveList from ReactiveUI and its [derived collection](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/derived-lists). It just works - no need to manualy fire Refresh

```
public class TweetsListViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    ReactiveList<Tweet> Tweets = new ReactiveList<Tweet>();

    IReactiveDerivedList<TweetTileViewModel> TweetTiles;
    IReactiveDerivedList<TweetTileViewModel> VisibleTiles;

    public TweetsListViewModel()
    {
        TweetTiles = Tweets.CreateDerivedCollection(
            x => new TweetTileViewModel() { Model = x },
            x => true,
            (x, y) => x.CreatedAt.CompareTo(y.CreatedAt));

        VisibleTiles = TweetTiles.CreateDerivedCollection(
            x => x,
            x => !x.IsHidden);
    }
}
```

If SPFetchCREntity does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged you can create dervied collection with reset argument, which is observable. Every time it ticks, whole list is filtered

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved dual filter issue. i got the idea from this link https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CollectionView-Tips-MVVM-d6ebb4a7

```
        public void searchMUID()
    {
        Muview = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = CRmappings2 }.View; //CRmappings2 is an observable collection and Muview is a public property of collectionview
        //FirstCRSP = AllCRSP;

        //muview.Filter = null;

        Muview.Filter = obj =>
        {
            SPFetchCREntity entity = obj as SPFetchCREntity;
            return obj != null && entity.SW_Version == SearchMU.ToString() && entity.MU_Identifier == Mupass.ToString();
        };
        Muview.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and mine?

Comment: @mm8 I have added this extra line `Muview = (CollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = CRmappings2 }.View;` this filters observable collection instead the icollection and this way i can preserve the filter applied on icollection

Comment: `new CollectionViewSource`  creates a new `CollectionViewSource` that you then cast to a `CollectionView` and nothing else.

Comment: And the answer to your actual question is that you will have to include both conditions in your predicate.

Comment: @mm8 how can i cast this to a list `AllCRSP = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CRmappings2);`

Comment: You can't because it isn't a list. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.